# Opencart display product category in a category page

Tags: php, html, mysql, opencart

Problem is this:  I need to display products category/categories name when I am displaying products on a category page. Is there any way of doing that

Basically it would look like that:
Category page

Product name
Belongs to - Subcategory1 name

Product name
Belongs to - Subcategory2 name

and etc.

Is there any way of doing that ?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do a lot of things for a lot of different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

thinking that you have a properly normalized database,

```
SELECT  `product`.`product_name` ,  `category`.`category_name` 
FROM  `product` 
JOIN  `category` ON  `category`.`category_id` =  `product`.`category_id`
```

loop through the results returned from above query where you can get product name and category and print them as you wish.

like  HawasKaPujaari said, there are lot of ways to do this :)